# Tonsuring head of new born

Tags: vedas, advaita, vedanta, sri-vaishnava, smarta

Apart from the family customs, is it alright to do the shaving head ceremony of the newborn after the first year is completed?

I have read in many places that the tonsuring is done before the first year is completed. Is it correct? If so, any specific reason?

Also, is there any difference in the months/years if the newborn is a male or female?

Can it be done right after one year is completed for the newborn?

Answer (score 2):

Tonsuring (Chudakaran) the head of the newborn is one of the ten sanskaras (Dasha Sanskaras) of the Aryas or Hindus. Sanskaras are practised according to the instructions in the Grihyasutras (part of Vedangas) and its commentaries. Different Vedas have their respective Grihyasutras. Depending on one who belongs to which Vedic school he should follow the instructions given in their respective Grihyasutras.

Apart from that Agamas also mentions these sanskaras. Different Hindu sects (Vaishnava, Shakta and Saiva) follow their respective Agamas.

Here I am giving the answer based on the Paraskara Grihyasutra, which belongs to the White Yajurveda and also from the Mahanirvana Tantra, which is a Shakta Agama (as I am a Shakta).

## Paraskara Grihyasutra (Adhyaya 2, Kandika 1)

> **1. When (the son) is one year old, the Cūḍākaraṇa (i.e. the tonsure of his head, should be performed),
>
> 2. Or before the lapse of the third (year).**

**The Procedure**

> 5. After food has been distributed to the Brāhmaṇas, the mother takes the boy, bathes him, puts on him an under and an upper garment which have not yet been washed, and putting him on her lap, she sits down to the west of the fire.

> 6. The father taking hold (of his wife) sacrifices Ājya oblations, and after he has partaken of the (sacrificial) food, he pours warm water into cold water with (the words), 'With warm water come hither, Vāyu! Aditi, cut the hair.'

> 8. He throws a piece of fresh butter, or of ghee, or some curds into it (i.e. into the water, Sara 6).

> 9. Taking some (water) he moistens the hair near the right ear with (the formula), 'On the impulse of Savitṛ may the divine waters moisten thy body in order that long life and splendour may be thine.'

> 10. Having unravelled (the hair) with a porcupine's quill that has three white spots, he puts three young Kuśa shoots into it with (the formula), 'Herb' (Vāj. Saṃh. IV, 1).

> 11. Taking up a copper razor with (the formula), 'Friendly by name' (Vāj. Saṃh. III, 63 a), he cuts (the hair) with (the formula), 'I cut off' (ibid. 63b), (and with the formula,) 'The razor with which Savitṛ, the knowing one, has shaven (the beard) of king Soma and Varuṇa, with that, ye Brāhmaṇas, shave his (head), in order that he may be blessed with long life and may reach old age.'

> 12. Cutting off (the Kuśa shoots) together with the hair, he throws them on a lump of bull's dung which they keep northwards of the fire.

> 13. In the same way two other times silently.

> 14. The moistening and the other rites are repeated with the two other (tufts of hair).

> 15. Behind with (the verse), 'The threefold age' (Vāj. Saṃh. III, 62).

> 16. Then on the left side with (the verse), 'With that prayer by which mayst thou, a mighty one, go to heaven, and long mayst thou see the sun: with that prayer I shave thee for the sake of life, of existence, of glory, of welfare.'

> 17. Three times he shaves round the head, from left to right;

> 19. (He recites the verse,) 'When the shaver shaves his hair with the razor, the wounding, the well-shaped, purify his head, but do not take away his life.'

> 21. With that water (Sūtras 6, 8) he moistens his head, and gives the razor to the barber with (the words), 'Without wounding him, shave him.'

> 22. The locks of hair which are left over, are to be arranged as it is considered auspicious (in his family).

> 23. Having put away that lump of dung with the hair so that it is hidden in a cow-stable, or in a small pond, or in the vicinity of water; he gives an optional gift to the teacher;

A more detailed instruction can be found in any of the commentaries on Paraskara Grihyasutra. For example, in Bengal, we follow Pashupati's commentary on Paraskara Grihyasutra.

## From Agama: Mahanirvana Tantra (Ullasa 9)

> I have done speaking of the rice-eating ceremony. **I shall now speak of the tonsure ceremony**. Do Thou listen (171).

> **In the third or fifth year,** according to the custom in the family, the tonsure of the boy should be performed for the success of the sacramental rites of the boy (172).

**The Procedure**

> The wise father should, after concluding the preliminary rites leading up to Dhara Homa, place on the north side of the Fire, called Satya, a mud platter filled with cow-dung, tila-seeds, and wheat, also a little lukewarm water and a keen-edged razor (173-174).

> The father should place the son on his mother’s lap, the mother sitting on her husband’s left, and, after breathing the Varuna Vija ten times over the water, rub the hair of the boy’s head with lukewarm water. He should then tie the hair with two blades of kusha grass into a knot, uttering meanwhile the Maya Vija (175-176).

> Then, saying the Maya and Lakshmi Vijas three times, he should cut off the knot with the steel razor and place it in the hands of the child’s mother (177).

> The boy’s mother should then take it with both hands and place it in the platter containing the cow-dung, and the father should then say to the barber: "Barber, do thou at thine ease proceed with the shaving of the boy’s hair, Svaha." Then, looking at the barber, he should make three oblations to Prajapati, into Vahni, under his name of Satya (178-179).

> After the boy has been shaved by the barber he should be bathed and adorned with clothes and jewels, and placed near the fire on the left of his mother, and the father should, after performance of Svishti-krit Homa and the expiatory rites, offer the complete oblation (180-181).

> Then, uttering the following:
> Hring, O Child! may the omnipresent Creator of the Universe grant thee well-being,
> he should pierce the ears of the boy with gold or silver needles (182).

> He should then sprinkle the child with water, uttering the
> O Water! thou art, etc. (aforementioned);
> and, after performing Shanti Karma and other rites, and making presents, bring the ceremony to a close (183).

> The sacramental rites from Garbhadhana to Chudakarana are common to all castes. But for Shudras and Samanyas they must be performed without Mantras (184).

> **In the case of the birth of a daughter all castes are to perform the rites without Mantras.** In the case of a daughter there is no Nishkramana (185).

---

References:

1. [Paraskara Grihyasutra translated by Hermann Oldenberg](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/paraskara-grihya-sutra/d/doc116632.html)
2. [Mahanirvana Tantra translated by Arthur Avalon](https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/mahanirvana-tantra-ebook.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain more, "In the case of the birth of a daughter all castes are to perform the rites without Mantras. In the case of a daughter there is no Nishkramana (185)." Also, what is "Nishkramana" ? What is the case of a daughter?

Comment: Nishkramana is another sanskara. Where the father takes his newborn son and goes outside of the house to show him the Sun. And pray that gods should allow my son to see the Sun for 100 years. If you find the answer useful, please accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me what is in the case of a daughter?

Comment: Nishkraman sanskra is omitted for daughters.

Comment: For tonsure, as you can see from the answer, the head will be shaved following the same procedure. But mantras won't be uttered. This is if you follow the Shakta Agama. But, if you follow the Vedic way, then as there is no special rule mentioned for daughters, the procedure is same for both son and daughter.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of tonsuring: (1) Vaidika vidhi and (2) Laukika vidhi.

Vaidika vidhi uses the Grihya-sutras and other Veda/Smriti texts as pramANa for doing so. There are vedic rituals and regulations for doing so. E.g. Apastamba sutra followers perform the chauLa samskAra at age 2 which requires performing a homa.

> [In the third year after his birth the Caula (or tonsure is performed)
> under (the Nakṣatra of) the two Punarvasus.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-grihya-sutra/d/doc116806.html)

Laukika vidhi is just unregulated family customs. Usually this is done after the first year and at a temple - typically the temple of the kula-devatA (personal family diety). Examples of such temples are Tirumala-Tirupati, Oppiliappan koil, etc. Since these are unregulated customs, they tend to change over time and are subject to whims of the followers. E.g.

1. In the last few years, people who live abroad and cannot come to India frequently perform this whenever they get the chance to visit India often before the first birthday.
2. People who perform more than one tonsure due to prayers or affiliations to more than one temple do it quickly one after the other (say with just 2 weeks gap).